# Java JDBC executeUpdate usage

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

This is part of a web application that get user input using GUI and creates a relational table in MySQL. The question is why is it that the table is not created? Using the debugger, the problem is during

```
st.executeUpdate(tableCreation.toString());
```

So I tried doing this

```
String[] Tables = {
        tableCreation.toString()
};

for (int i = 0; i < Tables.length; ++i) {
     st.executeUpdate(Tables[i]);
}
```

But it doesn't work too. The reason why I did the above is because the table is created when a static array String was used

```
static String[] Tables = {
    "create table STATE (" +
    "ABBREVIATION char(2) not null, " +
    "NAME varchar(32) not null, " +
    "ENTERED_UNION date null, " +
    "CAPITAL varchar(32) not null, " +
    "REGION varchar(16) not null, " +
    "AREA int not null, " +
    "FLOWER varchar(32) null, " +
    "BIRD varchar(32) null)"
};
```

When I used the static table, it works. So I am wondering what went wrong?

```
public String createButton1_action() {

    StringBuilder tableCreation = new StringBuilder();

    tableCreation.append("create table ").append(tableTF.getValue()).append(" (");

    StringBuilder primaryKey = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        // first get() returns the gridPanel, second get() returns the components within the panel
        TextField tempTF = (TextField) gridPanels.get(i).getChildren().get(1);
        // the table name from textfield
        tableCreation.append(tempTF.getValue()).append(" ");

        // the data type
        DropDown tempDP = (DropDown) gridPanels.get(i).getChildren().get(3);
        tableCreation.append(tempDP.getValue()).append(" ");
        // char/varchar amount
        if (tempDP.getValue().equals("CHAR") || tempDP.getValue().equals("VARCHAR")) {
            TextField charTF = (TextField) gridPanels.get(i).getChildren().get(4);
            tableCreation.append(charTF.getValue()).append(" ");
        }

        // primary key
        tempDP = (DropDown) gridPanels.get(i).getChildren().get(6);
        addPK(tempTF, tempDP, primaryKey);

        // nullable?
        tempDP = (DropDown) gridPanels.get(i).getChildren().get(8);
        tableCreation.append(tempDP.getValue());

        tableCreation.append(", ");
    }

    tableCreation.append("PRIMARY KEY (").append(primaryKey).append(")");
    tableCreation.append(")");

    String[] Tables = {
        tableCreation.toString()
    };

    try {
        // Get a connection from the connection factory
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB", "root", "onfigii");

        // Create a Statement object so we can submit SQL statements to the driver
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        // Submit the statement (Doesn't work too. It worked with a static table)
        for (int i = 0; i < Tables.length; ++i) {
            st.executeUpdate(Tables[i]);
        }

        // Why doesn't this work?
        st.executeUpdate(tableCreation.toString());

        // Close the statement
        st.close();

        // Close the connection
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreatePage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


    tableTF.setText(null);
    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        TextField tempTF = (TextField) gridPanels.get(i).getChildren().get(1);
        tempTF.setValue(null);
    }

    getApplicationBean1().refreshDataProvider();
    return null;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: "*Doesn't work*" is neither a valid MySQL error message nor a valid Java exception. You need to be a **lot** more specific.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it is a SQLException error. What happens is that from "st.executeUpdate(tableCreation.toString());", the error was caught in ex. For example, this was the sql "create table a (b DOUBLE null, c CHAR 10 NULL, d DATE NOT NULL, e VARCHAR 20 NULL, PRIMARY KEY (b, d)"

Comment: Every exception thrown by a JDBC driver is an `SQLException`. Be specific and include the stacktrace in your question

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, there is no stacktrace. What happens is that in the web, I have another dropdown that is a view which retrieves all the table store in the database. The table was never inserted. Even in debugging mode, I could follow it to the error where it will exit and proceed back to execute the rest of the code and the web page simply get refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the logic. Instead of

```
tableCreation.append(charTF.getValue()).append(" ");
```

It should be

```
tableCreation.append("(").append(charTF.getValue()).append(")").append(" ");
```

To answer my own question, there is nothing wrong with

```
st.executeUpdate(tableCreation.toString());
```

The reason why it didn't work in the first place was because the syntax for the creation of table was wrong to begin with. Hence the static String Table worked while the String created by logic didn't.

Answer (score 0):

it should be :

```
create table a
(b DOUBLE default null,
c CHAR (10) default NULL,
d DATE NOT NULL,
e VARCHAR (20) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (b, d)
);
```

can you show failed sql example?